# Date TV format appears differently in getResources template chunk

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-chunks, modx-getresources, modx-template-varaiables

I am using the Date TV with a custom format: `%b %e, %Y` which appears as: `May 6, 2015`.

However, I am having issues getting this to appear correctly within a getResource chunk, eg: `[[+tv.NewsDate]]`.

The date appears but doesnt follow the custom format. It revert back to the default.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to format the date during the output by an output filter `` [[+tv.NewsDate:strtotime:date=`%b %e, %Y`]] `` and set the output of the Date TV to standard. The output of the TV could be different from page to page with that.